# Visual Studio 11 CTP3 bugs?

Tags: c#, async-ctp, c#-5.0

Visual Studio 11 Preview bugs?

I tryed to compile following examples and receive unexpected compilation errors.

Example 1:

```cs
async = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
partial = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

class C
{

    async async async(async async) { } // ok

    async partial async(async async) { } // error CS1002: ; expected
}
```

Example 2:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class C
{
    delegate Task<dynamic> ady(dynamic i);

    delegate Task adv();

    void f()
    {

        ady d11 = new ady(async j => await j); // ok

        ady d12 = new ady((async j => await j)); // error CS0149: Method name expected

        ady d21 = new ady(async (j) => await j); // ok

        ady d22 = new ady((async (j) => await j)); // error CS0149: Method name expected

        adv d31 = new adv(async () => { dynamic d = 0; await d; }); // ok

        adv d32 = new adv((async () => { dynamic d = 0; await d; })); // error CS0149: Method name expected

        adv d41 = new adv(async delegate { }); // ok

        adv d42 = new adv((async delegate { })); // error CS0149: Method name expected

        adv d61 = new adv(async delegate { }); // ok

        adv d62 = new adv((async delegate { })); // error CS0149: Method name expected

        ady d71 = new ady(async delegate(dynamic d) { return await d; }); // ok

        ady d72 = new ady((async delegate(dynamic d) { return await d; })); // error CS0149: Method name expected
    }
}
```

Comment: Report CTP (and, when it is released, Beta) issues at http://connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
var a = new Action((() => {}));
```

doesn't compile in VS 2010, I think Example 2 is not a bug. Or if it is, it's not related to `async`.

Curiously, Resharper doesn't mark it as an error and

```
Action a = (() => {});
```

*does* work.

Comment: Yes, VS2010 doesn't compile your examle. But C# spec says that only namespace-or-type-name in parenthesized-expression is illegal.